# How to use mysql_fetch_row in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone tell me how to use `mysql_fetch_row` in CodeIgniter? My code is like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    for($i=1;$i<=$spasi;$i++){
        echo "|&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    if ($row[8] === 'Koleris') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=green>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === 'Melankolis') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=blue>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === 'Plegmatis') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=purple>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === 'Sanguins') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=red>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === '?') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=black>$row[8]</font>";
    } else {
        $keputusan = "<b>$row[8]</b>";
    }
    echo "<font color=red>$row[1]</font> = $row[2] (Koleris = $row[4], Melankolis = $row[5], Plegmatis = $row[6], Sanguins = $row[7]) : <b>$keputusan</b><br>";

    /*panggil dirinya sendiri*/
    get_subfolder($row[0], $spasi + 1);
}
```

What will the code be if we will use this code in CodeIgniter?

Comment: `foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch data from database in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867937/fetch-data-from-database-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @splash58 i have been using that but i got error "Message: Undefined offset: 8"

Comment: @RizalAhmad I'm not sure it's availiable to get indexed array in CI

Comment: Only you can use `$list_fields = $this->db->list_fields()` and change `$row[8]` to `$row[$list_field[8]]` if it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

Comment: how if we want to result like this : echo $row[2];

Comment: use this : $row = $query->row_array();

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}

Comment: I have been using that, but i got error Message: Undefined offset: 8

Comment: show me your data with field title. there is field name 8?

Answer (score 0):

To save your old code with minimal changes, you can try such approach

```
 while($row=$query->unbuffered_row()){
    $row = array_values($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this : -

`$result` contains multiple records from query

```
foreach($result as $row){

    for($i=1;$i<=$spasi;$i++){
        echo "|&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    if ($row[8] === 'Koleris') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=green>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === 'Melankolis') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=blue>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === 'Plegmatis') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=purple>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === 'Sanguins') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=red>$row[8]</font>";
    } elseif ($row[8] === '?') {
        $keputusan = "<font color=black>$row[8]</font>";
    } else {
        $keputusan = "<b>$row[8]</b>";
    }
    echo "<font color=red>$row[1]</font> = $row[2] (Koleris = $row[4], Melankolis = $row[5], Plegmatis = $row[6], Sanguins = $row[7]) : <b>$keputusan</b><br>";

    /*panggil dirinya sendiri*/
    get_subfolder($row[0], $spasi + 1);

}
```